# std::allocate_shared, allow shared pointer reference count to be allocated from from custom allocator and in single allocation

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, shared-ptr, allocator

Make shared improves performance using single allocation for reference count and object, is it possible to use custom allocator along with std::allocate_shared and still have one allocation, as per test code i have written its not happening:
 [sample](https://onlinegdb.com/BJJVJcEof)

I am aware of boost::intrusive, but it has additional code to be written and which can go wrong

Comment: actually it works a per my requirements, there is only one allocation done per object created using std::alloc_shared and with custom allocator. So I have the answer for my quiestion

Comment: Then please answer your own question below so it gets tagged as answered and potentially could help someone in the future

Answer (score 2):

with the help of some debugging found out that std::allocate_shared does what is expected, it allows you to make only one allocation for both your object as well as for reference counter.

below is corrected code:
[allocate shared](https://onlinegdb.com/SJVSU64jG)

Here operator new is called exactly once for both std::make_shared and std::allocate_shared. Using this object pool can be created and you can have same efficiency expected from boost::intrusive_ptr which needs additional coding.